# PHP form not inserting values into DB

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having an issue with a form I have created (Test purposes only, I am aware it's vulnerable to SQL Injection)

Basically, the form does not insert into the DB, yet it seems to be returning true on the script.

The code is as follows:

form.php

```
   <form action="create.php" method="post">
        <p>Username: <input type="text" name="username" />
        </p>
        <p>Password: <input type="password" name="password" />
        </p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Create" name= "cre" />
        </p>
    </form>
```

create.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$dbname = "obsidian";

if(isset($_POST['cre'])){


    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost','admin1', 'password1','obsidian' ) or die('Failed to connect to DB' . $mysqli->error );

    $hashed_password = password_hash($password,PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

         $registerquery = "INSERT INTO users (username, hash) VALUES('$username', '$hashed_password')";
        if($registerquery = true)
        {
            echo "<h1>Success</h1>";
            echo "<p>Your account was successfully created. Please <a href=\"index.php\">click here to login</a>.</p>";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<h1>Error</h1>";
            echo "<p>Sorry, your registration failed. Please go back and try again.</p>";    
        }       
     }   


  ?>
```

I get the success message, but as I stated, the values do not get inserted into the DB.

Any help would be good.

Comment: You never actually run the Insert query on the database.

Comment: ... and you're vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com)

Comment: do you make a difference between = and ==?

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). If you're having trouble with low-level database calls like this, I **strongly** encourage you to adopt a 
[development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) that fits your style and needs.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys - Sorry for being stupid, i'm new to this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This defines a query, but does **NOT** run it:

```
 $registerquery = "INSERT INTO users (username, hash) VALUES('$username', '$hashed_password')";
```

The this is NOT "testing" for success. It's simply seeing the variable to true:

```
    if($registerquery = true)
```

`=` is assignment, `==` is for equality testing.

Comment: Yeah, it still needs `prepare()`, `bind_param()` and `execute()` calls.

Answer (score 3):

You have to *query* the database. Try this:

```
$registerquery = "INSERT INTO users (username, hash) VALUES('$username', '$hashed_password')";

if ($mysqli->query($registerquery))
{
    // success.
}
else
{
    // failed.
}
```

Here is the documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

Answer (score 1):

You missed the step where you actually hand the SQL query to the database.

```
$mysqli->query($registerquery);
```

has to be run before it will be inserted.

You can also change your if statement to the following

```
if ($mysqli->query($registerquery))
```

Also, you're currently using a single `=`, which is setting `$registerquery` instead of checking its value.

Answer (score 1):

All you are doing here:

```
$registerquery = "INSERT INTO users (username, hash) VALUES('$username', '$hashed_password')";
if($registerquery = true)
```

is setting a string and then later setting the string to true. This is always going to return true. There are two problems with this:

- You need to execute the SQL statement that you have stored in the string for anything to happen in the database.
- You are not really checking the return value ("=="), but rather using "=", which simply sets the variable. A very common mistake.

Additionally, you should probably no longer use the mysqli built in functions, since they will soon be deprecated. I would recommend switching to [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) before moving any further.

Comment: he is not actually checking it

Comment: Duly noted, and edited. The most important point remains, which is that he is not executing any SQL statements at all. Not sure that this was deserving of a downvote.

Comment: I didn't downvote. No idea who does, but my answer got downvoted, too, so I am deleting it, because there are obviously too many stupid people around.

Comment: i downvoted the answer from user [Taco](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1075902/taco) for having only like 5 words in his answer. about 30 seconds after that, everyone elses answer got a downvote at the same time...

Comment: Thank you. I guess that explains it :)

Answer (score 1):

Formally, You should do something like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['cre'])){
  $username = $_POST['username'];
  $password = $_POST['password'];
  $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost','admin1', 'password1','obsidian' ) or die('Failed to connect to DB' . $mysqli->error );

  $hashed_password = password_hash($password,PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

  $registerquery = "INSERT INTO users (username, hash) VALUES('$username', '$hashed_password')";
  $stmt=$mysqli->prepare($registerquery);
  if($stmt->execute())
    {
        echo "<h1>Success</h1>";
        echo "<p>Your account was successfully created. Please <a href=\"index.php\">click here to login</a>.</p>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<h1>Error</h1>";
        echo "<p>Sorry, your registration failed. Please go back and try again.</p>";    
    }       
    $stmt->close();
 }
```

Also, you could call only mysqli_query

```
if($mysqli->query($registerquery)){
....
}
```

It would be enough. The first call is better if you need to bind parameters and make several calls to the same query with different values.

Regards.-